# Export Enterprise Architect Diagrams to XML, JSON or a Web-Friendly Format

Tags: javascript, architecture, uml, enterprise-architect

Is there a way to export Enterprise Architect diagrams into web-friendly, machine-readable formats (eg. JSON, XML,  etc) ?

I am trying to create a web-based user interface for displaying custom component diagrams that I create in EA.  I would like to both display these diagrams on a web page while also allowing users to update the diagram (via client-side scripting... perhaps a Javascript UML library or something else) and also store these diagrams in a more obscure data format on a remote data store.  If there is something easy to use in EA for this purpose, then please let me know.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [UMLCanvas](https://github.com/christophevg/UmlCanvas). It is an open source project I once participated in that did exactly what you described. At the time we stopped working on it all things you normally use on a class diagram were supported.

There was also a two-way interface for EA.

Here's an example of how it looks in a webpage
[image]

Comment: Thanks for all that wonderful info. I just realised from looking at the code in UMLCanvas that I could utilise the Enterprise Architect Automation Interface API via Java as well (UMLCanvas uses C# to use the EA model).  Nice project.

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis You can indeed use Java to use the API, but you can't use it to make an EA add-in because EA needs a COM visible dll for add-ins.

Answer (score 1):

You can export to XML schema from EA: from your project, select the menu option Tools, XML Schema, Generate XML schema.
A window will appear and you can select a few options, give a file name, and generate.
When you have generated your XML file, open it in any text editor, select the whole text and paste it in the left hand side window of the web page http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson.

This page will enable you to convert any XML to JSON (and vice-versa).

Comment: Is it possible to write a function in jscript, which can be used to create an XML-File ?  Like file-open, insert tags, file-close etc. (maybe using XMLWriter ?)